# Creating a username on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, user-accounts, stackexchange, user-profiles

When I created my account on Stack Exchange, I was simply assigned a number.  How can I change this to a chosen username?

Comment: Opening your profile and editing it should work.

Comment: My only options at Network Profile are Inbox and Achievements.  (I'm using a phone, if that matters.)

Comment: You can only edit your profile from the desktop version of the site.  To switch from mobile theme to desktop, click "full site" in the footer.

Comment: Alas, "full site" appears nowhere.  Guess I'll have to remain but a number.  I thank you, Normal Human - unlike myself - regardless!

Comment: Are you using an app? If yes, stop doing that and open the site in a browser.

Comment: OK, looked like that worked; let's see -

Answer (score 1):

Click your user avatar at the top of the screen to go to [your profile/activity page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/current).

Click Edit Profile & Settings

Change your "Display Name" to the desired value, and Save.

(You need to do this from the full desktop website. You can't do it from an app or from the mobile web site.)

Comment: +0.  This is almost correct, but not fully correct.  There are two ways to edit your display name using a mobile web browser.  First, visit your profile/activity page, then choose one of these two procedures.  1.  You can tap the "full site" link in the footer.  (You may need to tap the link a dozen times or so until it works.)  2.  Or use your mobile web browser's "request desktop site" feature, which will make your mobile device show you the non-mobile Stack Exchange website.

Comment: Those techniques simply request that the mobile browser open the full web site. It doesn't contradict what I said at all. I _didn't_ say you needed to use a desktop browser, just that it could only be done from the full, _non-mobile_, website.